# create dummy rows between two numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am implementing project in php where user have some books, with series number for example Book No.1 - series 151 to 175, that means book no.1 have 25 pages each pages have unique series no. from 151, 152... 175.

[image]

user uses one page of specific book for generating some type of voucher. sometimes two voucher can be generated for single page i.e. 151A & 151B.

[image]

so i need a sql query which return dummy rows from 1 to 175, and left joins with voucher table

just like this

[image]

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: i m using phpmyadmin  4.8.3

Comment: That's the version of phpmyadmin, which is a client. Try running the SQL query `SELECT @@version;` to find out the version of your MySQL Server. This is relevant because you need MySQL 8.0 or later to use recursive CTE queries as shown in the answer from @D-Shih.

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql version support CTE, you can try to use `CTE RECURSIVE` create a result set be the `Outer JOIN` table.

Or you can use `WHILE` with temp table to create a result set for series numbers.

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
    SELECT start_series,end_series
    FROM books
    UNION ALL
    SELECT start_series + 1,end_series
    FROM CTE
    WHERE start_series < end_series
)
SELECT c.start_series,
       coalesce(CONCAT(c.start_series,v.post_fix),v.voucher_page_no) voucher_no
FROM CTE c LEFT JOIN voucher v 
on c.start_series = v.voucher_page_no
ORDER BY c.start_series;

| start_series | voucher_no |
| ------------ | ---------- |
| 151          | 151A       |
| 151          | 151B       |
| 152          | 152        |
| 153          | 153        |
| 154          |            |
| 155          | 155        |
| 156          |            |
| 157          |            |
| 158          |            |
| 159          |            |
| 160          |            |
| 161          |            |
| 162          |            |
| 163          |            |
| 164          |            |
| 165          |            |
| 166          |            |
| 167          |            |
| 168          |            |
| 169          |            |
| 170          |            |
| 171          |            |
| 172          |            |
| 173          |            |
| 174          |            |
| 175          |            |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8UwXceUxpZ53iKMZoaULV5/0)